# What is the purpose of auditctl -a never,task?

Tags: amazon-ec2, audit

I see that whenever I start a new ec2 server the default rule for `auditctl`

is

```
auditctl -a never,task
```

What is the purpose of having this rule?

Answer (score 4):

From `man auditctl`

```
  -a [list,action|action,list]

          task        Add a rule to the per task list. This rule  list  is
                      used  only  at  the  time  a task is created -- when
                      fork() or clone() are called  by  the  parent  task.
                      When  using  this  list,  you should only use fields
                      that are known at task creation time,  such  as  the
                      uid, gid, etc.

          never       No audit records will be generated. This can be used
                      to suppress event generation. In general,  you  want
                      suppressions  at  the top of the list instead of the
                      bottom. This is because the event  triggers  on  the
                      first matching rule.
```

So this will stop `fork()` and `clone()` from generating audit logs, which could otherwise cause extra CPU load and I/O and disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

This rule prevents from all others from being parsed by audit.

- Task is the first step when audit context is allocated and linked off data structure.
- audit parses it's rules from first to last rule created and exits if rule is satisfied (ex. `-a never,task` which means to don't audit anything from task creation to task exit)
- it does provide better performance, but it's turning off syscall auditing completely

For further reading i recommend looking at [github repo](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace)

and [here](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/rules/10-no-audit.rules) is rule that defines auditd to be disabled by default